# Hibernate - setProjection after Criteria after Criteria

Tags: hibernate, spring, group-by, criteria, projection

why is this not possible?

```
Criteria crit1 =  sess.createCriteria(Criteria1Class.class);
Criteria crit2 = crit1.createCriteria("criteria2Class");

crit2.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("criteria2Property"));
List<String> l2 = crit2.list();
```

If I use this construction I get the error:

```
could not resolve property: criteria2Property of: com.foo.bar.models.Criteria1Class
```

offcourse criteria2Property doesn't exist in `Criteria1Class` because it exist in `Criteria2Class`

So why is this `groupProperty` not possible on the `@manyToOne` associations from `Criteria1Class` to `Criteria2Class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself:

```
Criteria crit1 =  sess.createCriteria(Criteria1Class.class)
                  .createAlias("criteria2Class","criteria2ClassAlias")
                  .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("criteria2ClassAlias.criteria2Property"));

crit1.list();
```